# How to disable BackgroundTransferRequest's TransferStatusChanged event handler after I unsubscribed it?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I'm using background transfer to download videos and I subscribed each request's TransferStatusChanged and TransferProgressChanged event to monitor it's status and download progress. When I cancelled one background transfer request using BackgroundTransferService.Remove() method, it fired TransferStatusChanged event [as msdn mentioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransferservice.remove%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). I don't want to execute event handlers, so I try to unsubscribe event before removed the request, like code below:

```
BackgroundTransferRequest transferToRemove = BackgroundTransferService.Find(requestId);
if (transferToRemove != null)
{
    transferToRemove.TransferStatusChanged -= transfer_TransferStatusChanged;
    transferToRemove.TransferProgressChanged -= transfer_TransferProgressChanged;
    BackgroundTransferService.Remove(transferToRemove);
}
```

but TransferStatusChanged event handler still fired. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundTransferService.Remove(transferToRemove); only Accepts the request. It will take sometime to remove it. Meanwhile, you again call the Add() function and thus you got one more event i.e. transfer_TransferProgressChanged.

In event transfer_TransferProgressChanged, first check BackgroundTransferService contains your request or not.

```
if(BackgroundTransferService.Requests.Contains(m_currentRequest))
{
  BackgroundTransferService.Remove(m_currentRequest);
  UnsubscribeYourEvents();
  DoOtherStuffRealtedToDownload();
}
```